# Mongoose not saving array elements

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm new to Node and Mongoose and I'm trying to build an application using MERN stack.

When I'm saving my data from my state to mongodb using mongoose the content of the array I'm trying to save does not actually get saved.

This is what my test data looks like when it gets sent from the client to the server: 
[image]

When I check Mongodb Atlas it looks like this:
[image]

The array seems to be empty there.

The corresponding model looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const LanesSchema = new Schema(
    {
        lanes: [
            {
                id: String,
                title: String,
                tasks: [
                    {
                        id: String,
                        title: String,
                        status: String,
                        description: String,
                        priority: String
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    { minimize: false }
);

const Lane = mongoose.model("Lanes", LanesSchema);

module.exports = Lane;
```

I was thinking there might be something wrong with the model here but I'm not sure.

I also tried this version right here but that did not work either:

```
const LanesSchema = new Schema([
    {
        id: String,
        title: String,
        tasks: [
            {
                id: String,
                title: String,
                status: String,
                description: String,
                priority: String
            }
        ]
    }
]);
```

The saving part of my code basically looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

const Lane = require("../models/lanes");

router.post("/save", (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;
    const newLane = new Lane(data);
    newLane.save(error => {
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).json({ msg: "Internal server error" });
            return;
        }
        res.json({
            msg: "We received your data!"
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the req.body formatted as JSON:

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "title":"Open",
      "tasks":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            "title":"Test task",
            "status":"Open",
            "description":"Test description",
            "priority":"High"
         },
         {
            "id":"4",
            "title":"Test task 4",
            "status":"Open",
            "description":"Test description",
            "priority":"Normal"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "title":"In Progress",
      "tasks":[
         {
            "id":"2",
            "title":"Test task 2",
            "status":"In Progress",
            "description":"Test description",
            "priority":"Normal"
         },
         {
            "id":"3",
            "title":"Test task 3",
            "status":"In Progress",
            "description":"Test description",
            "priority":"Normal"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"b0d547b1-f669-418e-8558-4739b15e1ef6",
      "title":"testLane",
      "tasks":[

      ]
   }
]
```

Right now I'm not sure what the problem is. So far I could not find a similar question yet.

If I'm missing some part of my code which might be the cause of the problem then please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add your req.body as json to the question?

Comment: @SuleymanSah I added the req.body. Does it have to be JSON?

Comment: It would be better in json format, so that we can compare it with schema.

Comment: @SuleymanSah Alright, I see. I updated my post again. Thanks for helping.

Comment: you are trying to add multiple entries but are using save, try using insertMany.

Comment: @sushantmehta this is working for me! thanks. the thing is, now for some reason after a few minutes there's another post request being sent without me doing anything. This should not be the case because I'm only sending a post req when submitting a form withing my app. I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @sushant mehta for commenting.

"you are trying to add multiple entries but are using save, try using insertMany."

This did the job for me.

My code now looks like this:

```
router.post("/save", (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;
    const newLane = new Lane();
    newLane.collection.insertMany(data, err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Multiple docs inserted");
        }
    });
});
```